# How to parameterise the delimiter for the Source in Azure Data Factory (V2) Data Flows?

Tags: csv, delimiter, azure-data-factory, parameterization

I have a situation where I am using Data Flows to ingest data from Blob Storage. The file format is CSV, however some files are comma delimited and some are pipe delimited.

It is possible to parameterise the delimiter of the dataset itself in ADF.

[image]

However in the Dataflow activity the Source Settings do not provide the option to either dataset parameters or change the delimiter.

[image]

It's not even possible to parameterise the choice of dataset. This means that I have to create a new Dataflow for each delimiter which is not practical.

Comment: Hi Adil Khan, If my answer is helpful for you, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Adil, Khan,  have you  tried this? If you still have questions, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this and it works well.

Source dataset parameter setting, add parameter `ColDelimiter`:

[image]

Create a pipeline parameter `ColDelimiter`:

[image]

Then click the Data Flow, we can set the source parameter:

[image]

When run the pipeline, we could set the column delimiter from paramter:
[image]

Hope this helps.